# Rephrase "growth/decrease rate"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to rephrase the following sentence (Intended to be used in an introduction passage of a paper, regarding a construct from chaos theory, the [Maximal Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent))

> The Maximal Lyapunov Exponent characterizes a system's average local growth/decrease rate of uncertainty.

In particular, I don't like the "growth/decrease" part. Is there any way to condense it into one word? ("change" doesn't seem appropriate) or else rephrase the whole sentence?

I wasn't sure what tags to use, feel free to add anything that seems appropriate.

Comment: As I understand it, this value reflects how two initially close dynamic values either diverge (positive exponent, difference moves to infinity) or converge (negative exponent; difference moves to zero). So I suppose the "uncertainty" here boils down to looking at the *current* value to decide whether it's getting nearer to **0** or **∞**. So perhaps you might refer to it as reflecting the ***speed of resolution*** (how ***quickly*** does some "difference" in a series "resolve" - either converging to **0** or diverging to **∞**).

Comment: I fail to understand why you dismiss "change" as inappropriate. It seems perfectly appropriate to me. Indeed ideal. Furthermore, I fail to understand why upon linking to the actual definition of the exponent you would want to try and come up with a completely different definition of your own. Please explain.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not precisely. First, we are usually talking about systems with bounded state spaces, so the difference cannot grow to infinity. Rather, the exponential growth rate holds only locally at each point (for as long as a linear approximation at that point holds).

Comment: When talking about uncertainty, I'm referring to the fact that we don't have infinite precision in specifying the value of the current state, and so it should be thought of not as a point in state space, but as a *sphere* with radius proportional the size of the measurement error, and the size of the uncertainty grows when we run the equations and try to predict where the state will evolve to . This is always true for any dynamical system, but in a chaotic system this uncertainty grows *exponentially* fast with time

Comment: @RegDwigнt For a given system, the uncertainty either grows or decreases, "change" sounds to me like something that can grow for some time and then decrease. The actual definition of a the exponent is a rigorous mathematical definition (which shows up a couple of paragraphs later). I'd like to first introduce some intuition

Comment: I have very little intuitive understanding of the subject matter here (perhaps partly because I somehow managed to avoid learning *differential calculus* even though I was formally studying maths right up until I left school to start my degree). But I feel that I've gained at least a "glimmering" of understanding from what's been written on this page (whereas I got pretty much *nothing* from poring over the relevant Wikipedia page for a minute or two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask, "Is there any way to condense it into one word? ("change" doesn't seem appropriate) or else **rephrase the whole sentence**?"

I would take the latter approach. You might try something like:

> The Maximal Lyapunov Exponent characterizes the average rate at which a system's local uncertainty *either grows or decreases* over time.

This captures the idea that the rate is not merely variable, though if you need to be more clear about that idea, it might be better presented in a second sentence.

Comment: This seems most appropriate to me, although I'd rather use *grows or shrinks* or *increases or decreases* as a more exact pairing of words.

Answer (score 1):

How about "decay" instead of decrease? Or maybe reduction in place of decrease. Fluctuation could be used in place of both.

Answer (score 0):

> The Maximal Lyapunov Exponent characterizes a system's average local ***change*** rate of uncertainty.

I see no reason to discount the word change, even when applied to this area of science. Why obfuscate your meaning with jargon?